# Send login values from Iphone to a C# REST Service

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, rest, httprequest

In my application I have 3 values I want to send to my REST Service written in C#, Username, Password and the Iphones UUID.
How can I easily transmit the 3 values to the REST Service and access them there in a method (C#)?
Then in the response I should get "Login success" or "Login failed".
You should know I use storyboard and arc.
Anyone got a simple example which is easy to understand? (I am new at iPhone programming)
I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Comment: Unrelated note: remember to never ever let that data leave the device unencrypted

Comment: one thing you must know is accessing UDID in ios will cause your app get rejected. If you are generating your own UUID than its ok.. but I think you are accessing UDID using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uinqueIdentifer];` right?

Comment: yes i will generate my own UUID later, first i want that the transmission of the data works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new MVC 4 came something called [Web.API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). It's great for creating REST services.
[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC4-and-WebAP) you can find some basic step-by-step tutorial about setting up Web.API service.

Comment: i have already a MVC 4 REST Service, i just want to know how i can send the data from the iphone to the rest service and access them there.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I focused on "C#" part. I don't know much about iPhone programming so I can't really help You here.

Comment: I need help by both parts :)
1. send data from iphone
2. create a method there to access he data from the httprequest

Comment: In the second link I've provided You can find information about creating server-side methods.